# Using -XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving with -XMultiParamTypeClasses

Tags: haskell, ghc, derived-instances

The following code results in an error:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, MultiParamTypeClasses, StandaloneDeriving #-}

class Module a b where
    (*>) :: a -> b -> b

data D
newtype DWrapper = DW D    
instance Module D D    
deriving instance Module DWrapper DWrapper
```

The error:

```
No instance for (Module DWrapper D) arising from a use of ‘Main.*>’
In the first argument of ‘GHC.Prim.coerce’, namely
  ‘(Main.*>) :: DWrapper -> D -> D’
In the expression:
    GHC.Prim.coerce ((Main.*>) :: DWrapper -> D -> D) ::
      DWrapper -> DWrapper -> DWrapper
In an equation for ‘*>’:
    (*>)
      = GHC.Prim.coerce ((Main.*>) :: DWrapper -> D -> D) ::
          DWrapper -> DWrapper -> DWrapper
When typechecking the code for  ‘Main.*>’
  in a derived instance for ‘Module DWrapper DWrapper’:
  To see the code I am typechecking, use -ddump-deriv
```

So GHC is looking for a `Module DWrapper D` instance to derive the requested `Module D D` instance. This is reasonable I guess, but not what I intended. Is there a way to tell GHC which instance to derive from? How does GNTD work on MPTCs?

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now, but you might try standalone deriving. If that doesn't work, you can build it manually using coercions if you need the efficiency boost.

Comment: @dfeuer I am using `StandaloneDeriving`, see the language pragmas. I'm not concerned about efficiency per se, really just expediency.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't look closely enough. No, you can't really tell `deriving` what to do the way you're trying to, and `MPTC` is throwing a wrench into the machine. I don't know if a functional dependency would help anything even if one were acceptable to you.

Comment: I reckon fundeps wouldn't help either, at least I have run into error messages along the lines “can't derive instance with associated type, not even with cunning generalized deriving”. — No, I really don't think it's possible to derive instances like this, at all. Should be a pretty tractable job for TH or even CPP, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, [`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html#generalized-newtype-deriving) only works on the *last* parameter of a multi-parameter typeclass. Even with [standalone deriving](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html#stand-alone-deriving):

> - The stand-alone syntax is generalised for newtypes in exactly the same way that ordinary `deriving` clauses are generalised ([Section 7.5.5, “Generalised derived instances for newtypes”](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html#newtype-deriving)). For example:
>
>   ```
>   newtype Foo a = MkFoo (State Int a)
>   deriving instance MonadState Int Foo
>   ```
>
>   GHC always treats the *last* parameter of the instance (`Foo` in this example) as the type whose instance is being derived.

(BTW, I tried searching for any relevant GHC trac bug report or feature request, but couldn't find any.)

Comment: There are no tickets because it is not a bug. The only way to do this without ambiguity would be to allow the programmer to specify which instance to derive from.